# How much cm needed for airflow? - optimal window shutter distance

Tags: airflow

I am thinking that air (if it is still) is a very good insulator.

So why aren't we putting the window shutter far away from the window?

It would have more air between the window and the shutter and the **Question**:  it would cause better insulation?

Or above a few centimeters thickness, the airflow would start anyways by itself and it would just only backfire?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of the question here.  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/wouldnt-it-be-most-effective-to-insulate-a-house-with-just-an-air-space/24836#24836

Comment: I cannot comment there (not having 50 points) to ask for further infos in the link you mentioned :\

because on that link I don't understand what are the letters mentioned in the formulas.

can you pls update that answer with more details on what is what, ex.: what is "A" or "ΔT"

or would my theory work? to make the distance bigger between the windows and the shutter

many thanks :)

Comment: I have updated the explanation and added examples.

Comment: Another bounced question, user not seen for a long while...

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the window shutters and windows is mostly dependant on the thickness of the walls.

Air can flow through much smaller space such as the fins of amplifiers heat sinks or many electronics heatsinks that don't use a fan.